# Flutter: how to make card expand to whole screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I have some cards in `gridview`. I want `ontap` of any card, they should expand to whole screen.

this are the cards,

HAVE TO DELETE IMAGES BECAUSE OF CONFIDENTIALITY

I want them to expand to whole screen like this,

what I have tried,

-> I have tried using `OpenContainer` widget,

-> custom hero animation

but they both use `pageroute` but I want them to do it without the page route because there is some content like `appbar` which would be same for both screen so I don't want them rebuild it everytime user tap on any of the card.
if anyone can lead me to right direction that would be awesome

Comment: maybe use `OverlayEntry`? are you familiar with flutter's overlays?

Comment: @pskink sorry never heard of that le me check

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this package: https://pub.dev/packages/animations

if you don't like using `pageroute` you can just switch your widget using `StatefulWidget` and `Visibility`.

And wrap your `Card` with `InkWell` then use the `onTap / onPressed` callback to set change the state so the `Visibility` will start work now

1. Create a function

```dart
Widget transition(Widget _child) {
  return PageTransitionSwitcher(
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
    transitionBuilder: (
      Widget child,
      Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
    ) {
      return SharedAxisTransition(
        child: child,
        animation: animation,
        secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
        transitionType: SharedAxisTransitionType.horizontal,
      );
    },
    child: _child,
  );
}
```

2. Add it on your scaffold:

```dart
    transition(child:condition ? widget_1 : widget_2);
```

Comment: I have seen this package that's where I got the `OpenContainer` widget but still uses `pageroute` under the hood

Comment: Check my edit brother, neither OpenContainer or pageroute i used, just a simple function from animation package my man.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you meant by expand to the whole screen, but you probably need to use the Hero() widget, wrap each widget you want to expand with a `Hero()` widget and give it a `tag: 'spo2'` for example, make a new screen for the second image, wrap each card with a Hero() and the same tag in the previous screen for the expanded card.

For further reading check out https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Hero-class.html

Comment: I mean to say that it should work like pop up and fill the screen with second image content under the `appBar` but not navigation to another screen like `expansionTile` widget

Answer (score 0):

Try using a dialogue and animating the opening.